# Django EmailMessage - dump object as string

Tags: python, django

I already know how to send email messages with Django EmailMessage object:

```
msg = EmailMessage(title, body, from, [to], headers=headers)
msg.send()
```

Now I need to get a textual representation of MIME message as a python string (to pass to 3rd-party system).

like

```
mime_text = msg.as_string()
```

Unfortunately, documentation doesn't shed any light on how to do it (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/).

There is a clue of custom email backend implementation, but i'm sure, there should be a simpler way (also i need just specific messages, not all of them)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EmailMessage class has a method `message()`, which returns a SafeMIMEText instance which in turn has an `as_string()` method. So:

```
mime_text = msg.message().as_string()
```